# Vlookup and & used in a nested fomat

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use `Vlookup` and `&` in a nested format, while trying to get the `Vlookup` to search another Excel file with a certain sheet name introduced in `O24&B2&Q24` cells.

My formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,O24&B2&Q24,2,FALSE)
```

I am getting an error (which I think comes from when the formula is simplified):

```
Vlookup(A1, "'k/:file_location_[filename.xlsx]_sheetname_searcharea"), 2 FALSE)
```

I feel like the double quotations "" around my file path is making my syntax wrong. I have already tried `substitute` and it's not working.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the error or introduce a better approach?

Comment: Research `INDIRECT`. You'll need to have the `filename.xlsx` workbook open for this to work though.

Comment: @BigBen i know this method, but if i can avoid the need to open the other work book, would be much better.

Comment: You can't, sorry. At least not with regular formulas.

Comment: so using =VLOOKUP(A1,O24&B2&Q24,2,FALSE) is a dead end?

Comment: Yes, that approach is a dead end.

Comment: yes, it is a dead end.  The cells hold stings and not actual references, and even if they were actual references using `&` would make them a string and a string is a string and not a valid reference.  That is why INDIRECT was created.  It turns a string to a valid reference.  But it is volatile and is why it requires that the workbook be open.